# TextToSpeech:service isn't started?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

Hey i a creating app which is TextToSpeech functionality. I write code and run but no any
speech  is generate. some error display in logcat. here is logcat

```
04-11 20:21:30.099: VERBOSE/TtsService(481): TtsService.setLanguage(eng, USA, )
04-11 20:21:30.109: INFO/TextToSpeech.java - speak(849): speak text of length 41
04-11 20:21:30.109: ERROR/TextToSpeech.java - speak(849): service isn't started
```

I don't understand how to solve this...here is my full code.

```
public class ExamAppearingActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener 
{
 private int MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE = 0;    
 private TextToSpeech tts;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.examquestionscreen);
            if (isVoiceEnabled==1)
        {

            tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

            final List<ObjectiveWiseQuestion> QuestionWiseProfile1= db.getOneQuestion(examId);       

            for (final ObjectiveWiseQuestion cn : QuestionWiseProfile1)
            {   
                Intent checkIntent = new Intent();
                checkIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
                startActivityForResult(checkIntent, MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE);

                db=new MySQLiteHelper(getBaseContext());
                db.getWritableDatabase();    
                counter=cn.getCounter();

                String question="Question is "+cn.getQuestion();
                String option1="Option A is "+cn.getOptionA();
                String option2="Option B is "+cn.getOptionB();
                String option3="Option C is "+cn.getOptionC();
                String option4="Option D is "+cn.getOptionD();
                tts.speak(question, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                tts.speak(option1, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                tts.speak(option2, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                tts.speak(option3, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
                tts.speak(option4, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
              }
       }
   }

 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == MY_DATA_CHECK_CODE) {
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {
                // success, create the TTS instance
                tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

            } 
            else {
                // missing data, install it
                Intent installIntent = new Intent();
                installIntent.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);

               //tts.isLanguageAvailable(Locale.INDIA_HINDI);
                startActivity(installIntent);

            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) 
    {        
        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) 
        {
            // tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);

            Locale loc = new Locale ("hi_IN");
            tts.setLanguage(loc);

            Toast.makeText(ExamAppearingActivity.this,"Text-To-Speech engine is initialized", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (status == TextToSpeech.ERROR) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(ExamAppearingActivity.this, "Error occurred while initializing Text-To-Speech engine", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
```

This code is run only when i add it on button click but i need to start it from
onCreate()  method.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `tts` until `onInit` has been called.

At the moment, you create it and try to use it within the `onCreate` method, but it won't have finished being initialised by then.

You're also creating `tts` twice. The one in `onActivityResult` makes most sense because you're checking it exists first. I'd get rid of the creation in `onCreate`, and put all of the actual speaking into `onInit`.